# How to edit internal dependencies Library onRender deployment?

Tags: python, flask, deployment, pip

I've created a Flask project and deployed it on Render. The project is about automating Instagram posts using the `instabot` library. In my 'api.py' file, there is some code that was preventing me from posting frequently based on the number of requests. On my local machine, I was able to comment out that code, and it worked fine. However, I'm facing issues with deployment on Render. How can I comment out that code in the Render deployment service?

the path is `venv\Lib\site-packages\instabot\api`
the code

```
       ....
       self.logger.info("Full Response: {}".format(str(response)))
                try:
                    self.logger.info("Response Text: {}".format(str(response.text)))
                except Exception:
                    pass
            '''if response.status_code == 429: #commented line
                # if we come to this error, add 5 minutes of sleep everytime we hit the 429 error (aka soft bann) keep increasing untill we are unbanned
                if timeout_minutes is None:
                    timeout_minutes = 0
                if timeout_minutes == 15:
                    # If we have been waiting for more than 15 minutes, lets restart.
                    time.sleep(1)
                    self.logger.error(
                        "Since we hit 15 minutes of time outs, we have to restart. Removing session and cookies. Please relogin."
                    )
                    delete_credentials()
                    sys.exit()
                timeout_minutes += 5
                self.logger.warning(
                    "That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep "
                    "for {} minutes.".format(timeout_minutes)
                )
                time.sleep(timeout_minutes * 60)
                return self.send_request(
                    endpoint,
                    post,
                    login,
                    with_signature,
                    headers,
                    extra_sig,
                    timeout_minutes,
                )'''
            if response.status_code == 400:
                response_data = json.loads(response.text)
                if response_data.get("challenge_required"):
                    # Try and fix the challenge required error by totally restarting
                    self.logger.error
            ....
```